# How to calculate mean for multiple raster files and multiple variables using R

Tags: raster, r, stack, average

[image: Folder with multiple raster files]I have a folder with multiple raster files (.asc) which contains the biomass of different fish species (e.g., Anglerfish, Bathydemersal etc) for different years (e.g., 00012, 00024, 00036 etc)
I want to calculate the mean per species using R
So far i have done the following:

```
files_path <- "~/new/asc/" #path where my files are    
all_files <- list.files(files_path,
                            full.names = TRUE,
                            pattern = ".asc$") #take all the ascii files in    
files_stack <- stack(all_files) #stack them together
```

Here comes the problem: `mean_ <- calc(files_stack, mean)` code makes one mean for the entire files_stack. [image: Mean for all the species in my stack]

I want to have mean per each species. Any tips on how to do it?

Comment: Which software are you working with?

Comment: Could you please describe your raster data? For example, what do the pixel values indicate for each raster? Are you looking for the average pixel value for each raster?

Comment: When you say "mean_ <- calc(files_stack, mean) code makes one mean for the entire files_stack" do you mean you get one single value out? Because you should get a raster with each pixel as the mean of each pixel in the stack.

Comment: Aaron, I would like to have a new raster per species where each cell is the mean of those specific cells for all those years for a particular species..

Comment: Exactly Spacedman, I get a raster where each pixel is the mean of each pixel in the stack

Comment: But how does each layer define which species and how much biomass at a given time? I think you really need to explain and maybe plot some to show us what you've got.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a stack of rasters loaded, you can operate on groups of them using `stackApply`. You have to create a vector of the groups.

In your case the grouping is the species. Extract the species from the file name using some string processing.  For example if your file paths are like this:

```
> all_files
 [1] "./EcospaceMapBiomass-Anglerfish-00012.asc"   
[etc]
 [7] "./EcospaceMapBiomass-Anglerfish-00084.asc"   
 [8] "./EcospaceMapBiomass-Bethydemersal-00012.asc"
 [9] "./EcospaceMapBiomass-Bethydemersal-00024.asc"
[10] "./EcospaceMapBiomass-Bethydemersal-00036.asc"
[etc]      
[18] "./EcospaceMapBiomass-Shark-00048.asc"        
[19] "./EcospaceMapBiomass-Shark-00060.asc"        
[20] "./EcospaceMapBiomass-Shark-00072.asc"        
[21] "./EcospaceMapBiomass-Shark-00084.asc"
```

Then you can get the species by removing everything up to "mass-" with nothing, and then everything from the remaining "-" to the end with nothing. This will probably fail if you have a "-" in a species name. Check that. So this:

```
species = gsub("-.*.asc","",gsub(".*mass-","",all_files))
```

nets you:

```
> species
 [1] "Anglerfish"    "Anglerfish"    "Anglerfish"    "Anglerfish"   
 [5] "Anglerfish"    "Anglerfish"    "Anglerfish"    "Bethydemersal"
 [9] "Bethydemersal" "Bethydemersal" "Bethydemersal" "Bethydemersal"
[13] "Bethydemersal" "Bethydemersal" "Shark"         "Shark"        
[17] "Shark"         "Shark"         "Shark"         "Shark"        
[21] "Shark"
```

You could also do this with `strsplit` or one of a number of other ways. However you do it, end up with a vector of species that match each item in your list of files.

Then `stackApply`.

```
> files_stack <- stack(all_files) 
> means = stackApply(files_stack, indices=species, fun=mean)
> means
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 4, 4, 16, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : index_Anglerfish, index_Bethydemersal, index_Shark 
min values :      0.006978279,         0.006978279, 0.006978279 
max values :        0.9034359,           0.9034359,   0.9034359
```

`means` is now a brick with 3 layers, each one a map of the mean for a species, and the layer names give you the species. These are all identical because all my inputs were identical. Test with better simulated data to make sure this is actually correct, or make sure the answer with real data looks reasonable.

Comment: Ha, you just beat me to the punch with exactly the same answer. Good thing it is not a competition.

Comment: The only thing that I would add here is the use of `list.files(getwd(), "asc$")` to create the "all_files" object. If you are not in the directory that the files reside you can specify a path as the first argument and then use the `full.names = TRUE` argument to return the full paths but, then you have the directory separators, in addition to the dashes, to deal with when splitting the string.

Comment: fantastic! thank you @Spacedman, it worked perfectly!!